# CSS alignment with Checkbox List (runat=Server)

Tags: html, css, vb.net, checkbox

I have looked at solutions to my issue, such as https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6930648/revisions however whilst these place the first line of text where I want it the second and third line, which drop below to checkbox, are not lined up with the first as they line up underneath the checkbox itself.

I have played with 'word-wrap' and inherts as well but have not got a working solution. There code below displays only the first line correctly.

Code I am using:

CSS -

```
#CheckListWrapper 

 label
 {

     margin-left:30px;     
     width: 500px;
  }
```

VB

```
 <div id="CheckListWrapper">
        <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="CheckBoxList1"  CssClass="CheckboxList">
     </asp:CheckBoxList></div>  <!-- CheckListWrapper -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `RepeatLayout="UnorderedList"` for the `<asp:CheckBoxList` control and then style the layout using custom CssClass. You can use following style with some modifications as you required. If you want to align the checkboxlist in a single line, you can change `li` display to `inline-block` etc. and

```
.checkbox-list-block {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}
.checkbox-list-block li {
display:block;
}
.checkbox-list-block li label {
display:inline-block;
margin-left:4px;
}
.checkbox-list-block li input[type="checkbox"] {
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

According to: [CheckBoxList.RepeatLayout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.repeatlayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Two options are new as of ASP.NET 4: OrderedList and UnorderedList.

Also, please refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatlayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The text is affected by the CSS but the left align is affects when next to the checkbox still.

Comment: please try to alter css or add some attributes to get what you wanted.